# Por que o Google Chrome acusa que está faltando jquery.min.map?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Baixei a versão do [jQuery 1.10.1 minimizado](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js) e o Google Chrome está alertando nas ferramentas para desenvolvedor, aba Network, que `jquery.min.map` não foi encontrado: **erro 404**

Observação: O jQuery funciona corretamente.

Esse `jquery.min.map` é uma nova dependência para usar jQuery?

Comment: Isso só acontece no Google Chrome?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Um arquivo `.map` permite mapear um arquivo javascript minimizado (*minified*) para o arquivo original. Então podemos depurar uma página web sem precisar alterar o sistema no servidor, ou seja:

- Sem mais gambiarras para colocar o jQuery original em modo "desenvolvimento" e o jQuery *min* em modo produção
- O código executado no navegador continua sendo o *minified*, mas você consegue ver o trecho orignal equivalente de forma que pode entender o que está acontecendo

Existem outros detalhes, vantagens e aplicações que podem ser lidos no artigo [*Introduction to JavaScript Source Maps*](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/?redirect_from_locale=de).

Quanto ao Chrome, ele tenta baixar o mapa sempre que encontra uma referência no arquivo javascript. Exemplo:

```javascript
/*! jQuery v1.10.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map
*/
```

Para evitar os erros, remova o trecho do arquivo Javascript ou desabilite este recurso do navegador através da opção `Enable Source Maps`, conforme a imagem abaixo (extraído do artigo citado):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 12):

O arquivo minificado perde informações que podem ser úteis no momento de exibir detalhes de um erro, como o *backtrace*. O JQuery vem com um arquivo **.map** que dá essa informação adicional ao navegador, de forma que você pode usar a biblioteca minificada e, ao mesmo tempo, não ver mensagens incompreensíveis de erro.

Se você está em um ambiente de produção, o arquivo **.map** não é necessário, afinal, é esperado que nenhum erro ocorra. Use apenas durante o desenvolvimento.

[jquery-1.10.1.min.map](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.map)

Comment: Mas este arquivo só é requisitado quando ocorrem erros?

Comment: No caso do *Google Chrome* você pode abrir as *Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor* (F12), abrir as configurações (ícone no cando inferior direito) e desmarcar "Enable JS source maps". O arquivo será usado apenas para exibir informações nesse painel e não apresenta nenhum efeito na página para o usuário final.